# Converting from matlab code to c++

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-coder

I want to convert this MATLAB  code to c++

```
function [ c ] = main() 
%#codegen
coder.inline('never'); 

c = imread('focus.jpg');
```

but it gives me this `error :  The function 'imread' is not supported for standalone code generation. See the documentation for coder.extrinsic`  ??!!

Comment: Have you read `coder.extrinsic`? It explains how to solve it for target systems with matlab installed.

Comment: i put this statement : coder.extrinsic('imread');
and it just give me another error

Comment: Failed to eliminate a use of the MATLAB function 'imread'. For non-simulation builds, uses of unsupported MATLAB functions are eliminated if they do not affect function outputs.

Answer (score 1):

The function " imread " is not supported in matlab coder , but it is supported by  matlab compiler by using the keyword `deploytool` in the command window of matlab .